# Trying to learn programming; I suck at command prompt

Tags: python, command-line

I know this is really basic but it is frustrating.  I'm using Python 2 to try and create my first program (in Windows 7 64bit).  Every guide I look at says to install Python2, then go to the command prompt and type `python`.  But... I get an error, because python.exe is not in that directory.  So I change to the "python27" directory, and it runs fine.  But then when I want to run a program, I type `python HelloWorld`, but of course that doesn't work.  I need to be in the directory that has both the python.exe, *and* the directory that has my program file.

Surely everyone does not have all of their programs in the python install directory; what am I missing?

Comment: put the python directory in your PATH ?

Comment: How are you installing python? It should be added to your path automatically, no?

Comment: @Mauricio, You should make that an answer and add info about how the PATH works. Alternatively, @Billy - google: PATH environment variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add c:\Python27\ to your path. [Try this explanation.](http://windows7forums.com/tweaks-guides-howto/48857-environment-variables-windows-7-a.html)

Answer (score 3):

You have basically two possibilities:

1. Use the full path to the Python interpreter when starting you program, e.g. `c:\Python2.7\python.exe HelloWorld`
2. Add the directory of the Python interpreter to your PATH environment variable. I can't tell you how to do this in Windows 7, though.

Answer (score 0):

As 'doze doesn't recognise .py files as well as .bat or .exe, you probably have to say python.exe HelloWorld.py for it to work correctly [I think the tutorial was designed for linux users]. And as the python interpreter is now part of your path [see previous answer, more help at http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGLL_enAU399AU399&q=win7+add+to+path ] you can instead type HelloWorld.py on the command line and it will know to look for the python interpreter.
Another option - the idle editor comes as part of the default 'doze install. If you use it to edit .py files you can run them from within the editor by pressing F5.